# Add Brackets to Timestamp

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm new to PHP so I don't know whether this is possible.

I need to add brackets to different timestamps so that this:

```
<span class="time">2:26</span>
<span class="time">2:51</span>
<span class="time">3:37</span>
<span class="time">1:19</span>
```

becomes this:

```
<span class="time">(2:26)</span>
<span class="time">(2:51)</span>
<span class="time">(3:37)</span>
<span class="time">(1:19)</span>
```

**EDIT**

The above HTML is generated using a simple DOM parser to grab info from a webpage.

Comment: Is this existing HTML, or are you building this HTML using PHP to begin with?

Comment: I've added some extra info to the OP to explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is part of a larger HTML string or if the syntax might differ, it's a better idea to use a DOM parser.

However, if that isn't the case you can do this:

```
$string = str_replace('<span class="time">', '<span class="time">(', $string);
$string = str_replace('</span>', ')</span>', $string);
```

Or you can use regex:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<span class=\"time\">(\d+\:\d+)<\/span>/', '<span class="time">($1)</span>', $string);
```

Comment: I've actually used a DOM parser to grab this info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your timestamp string is in $timestamp variable, you could use concatenation, ie.:

```
$output = '(' . $timestamp . ')';
```

Or as you mentioned, using a regular expression to validate the string before addind brackets:

```
$output = preg_replace("/(\d+):(\d+)/", "($0)", $timestamp);
```